# Https Redirect issue on Google app engine in laravel application

Tags: google-app-engine, redirect, laravel-5, https

I have laravel (v5.6) application on Google app engine.

How to redirect to https from http?

Comment: standard or flexible environment?

Answer (score 3):

**In App Engine Standard:**

Use the `secure: always` element in the handlers of your app.yaml.

Quoting the App Engine [standard app.yaml reference documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/config/appref#handlers_secure_always):

> Requests for a URL that match this handler that do not use HTTPS are automatically redirected to the HTTPS URL with the same path. Query parameters are preserved for the redirect.

```
handlers:
- url: /youraccount/.*
  script: auto
  secure: always
```

**In App Engine Flexible:**

In this case, as App Engine Flexible does not support handlers, you need to redirect to HTTPS from within your application.

Take a look at [this document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/upgrading#authentication_changes):

> **Secure handlers:**
>
> The `secure` setting under `handlers` is now deprecated for the App Engine flexible environment. If you need SSL redirection, you can update your application code and use the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header to redirect `http` traffic. You can also use the [HTTP Strict Transport Security response header](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_Cheat_Sheet).